# Is there a parametrization for the shape of space?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I was thinking about how the space is curved. And how do we know that the shape of space arround a singularity is something like that:
[image]

So I was trying to make a similar parametrization of this kind of shape
For example:

$$X(y,\theta)=( -y(sin(\theta)),y(cos(\theta)), ln(y-\frac{1}{2}))$$ for $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ and $y\in(0,5)$
And I get something like this:

[image]

How can I describe the shape of space arround Earth for example?
Where should I look for this kind functions?

Comment: One can solve the equations of general relativity... but for Earth the result will not differ significantly from a 1/r potential (outside of the Earth). It won't make much of a difference for the sun, either. Having said that, the rubber surface model is not a good one, to begin with. It's one of those things that are popular but wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the infamous rubber sheet model of gravity, which is in various ways highly misleading.

The spacetime geometry around any spherically symmetric mass, whether it's a black hole or the Earth, is described by the Schwarzschild metric:

$$ ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)dt^2 + \frac{dr^2}{1-\frac{r_s}{r}}+r^2d\theta^2 + r^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2 $$

The diagram you show is a spatial hypersurface i.e. it is obtained by taking a moment in time so $dt = 0$. If we ignore the angular terms then the metric simplifies to:

$$ ds = \frac{dr}{\sqrt{1-\frac{r_s}{r}}} $$

Integrate this and you get:

$$ s = \sqrt{r(r - r_s)} + \tfrac{1}{2}r_s \ln \left( 2\sqrt{r(r - r_s)} +2r - r_s\right) $$

And in your rubber sheet diagram this is the equation for the vertical displacement as a function of $r$. Rotate around the $s$ axis to generate the surface.

But while it's fun to play with these diagrams I must emphasise that generations of physics students have been lead astray by taking the rubber sheet metaphor too seriously. While it's pretty good for popular science TV programmes, if you're serious about physics you should banish it from your mind.

Comment: I'm a math student, I was just curious. Thank you, it is very helpful.

Comment: @I.S.Guerra: I copied and pasted the integral, and actually I think it's wrong. I'll check on the Wolfram integrator ...

Comment: Ok, no problem it was very clear anyway

Comment: OK I think it's correct now